# How to reverse these words in a string in-place using REGEXP?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, hashtable

[image]

The problem is like this, and below is my solution, however it does not work for ".". Anyone has some idea?

```
    function wordReverse(str) {

        var words = str.split(/\s+/);
        var result = "";
        console.log(words);
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            result += words[i].split('').reverse().join('')+" ";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/I0zTvj/1) that matches all characters that are not spaces or periods, and the callback option to reverse just the sequences of letters:

```js
var str = 'abc  Gómez   bcd.efg';

function wordReverse(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^\s.]+/g, function(m) {
    return m.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
}

console.log(wordReverse(str));
```

Comment: Welcome. Google "js regex exercises" (sans quotes).